# Create directory with path longer than 260 characters in Python

Tags: python-3.x, windows, filesystems

This is very similar question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31728889/create-directory-with-path-longer-than-260-characters), but for Python instead of powershell. It was also discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36219317/pathname-too-long-to-open/36219497), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29557760/long-paths-in-python-on-windows), but no working solutions are posted.

So, is there a way to create a directory in Python that bypasses the 260 char limit on windows? I tried multiple ways of prepending `\\?\`, but could not make it work.

In particular, the following most obvious code

```
path = f'\\\\?\\C:\\{"a"*300}.txt'
open(path, 'w')
```

fails with an error

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '\\\\?\\C:\\aaaaa<...>aaaa.txt'
```

Comment: Windows paths can be up to 32767 characters, as limited by NT's [`UNICODE_STRING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wudfwdm/ns-wudfwdm-_unicode_string) counted string type, give or take a few characters for the final resolved path (e.g. "C:" -> "\Device\HarddiskVolume2"). But the length of file and directory names is limited by the file system. Almost all supported file systems limit this to 255 characters. See [File System Functionality Comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/filesystem-functionality-comparison).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to eryksun I realized that I was trying to create a file with too long of a name. After some experiments, this is how one can create a path that exceeds 260 chars on windows (provided file system allows it):

```
from pathlib import Path

folder = Path('//?/c:/') / ('a'*100) / ('b'*100)
file = folder / ('c' * 100)

folder.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
file.open('w')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with the limit and I disabled this limit, because the r'\\?\' didn't help me. So as I found this question I want to answer it for others, and  I did this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0YpJUzqYQqI)

What helped me in the tutorial is the second solution so I will write it here:
Type in the search "gpedit.msc" and go to: Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Filesystem.

There you need to enable the "Enable Win32 long paths", close the editor and restart computer

The other solution is throuh the regisry editor, it can help:
Type  regedit in the search bar and goto

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem
```

change the key 'LongPathsEnabled' to 1. or simply run this command:

```
reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem /v LongPathsEnabled /t REG_DWORD /d 1
```

Good luck!